# Google Script and Google Sheets - Drop down to select cell and add value from input from sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been cobbling together script from other sources and feel like I am close but can't make that final leap on my own. Just to give you some background

I am putting together a document in Google Sheets where I can have a student input specific values from a live football game, that will be used on OBS to be displayed as real time stats for our video broadcast. I made a very simple button based sheet for basketball and it worked fantastically. [Picture of Google Basketball Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKm7s.png)

Football is a different beast. My concept is to have a sidebar where I have a set of names preselected in a drop down menu along with a second drop down menu with a preselected drop down of stat types (rush, passing....) these two drop downs will find the cell associated with both with Name rows) and stat type (column)  and a input field which adds value to selected cell.

I have not been able to figure out how to have a drop down menu associate with a specific cell, let alone two different drop downs. If the two drop downs isn't possible, I am happy with making a button to associate with specific plays then have a drop down of names along with an input field will work.

What I have so far - I have a drop down menu that pulls the names from Column A but when I select one, nothing happens. I also have a button that I can send a value to a specific cell, but it won't add to the original cell it just changes the cell to "Input value"1

```js
function ftball() {
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Sidebar');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function getNames() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Football");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}

// Sets the value of A1 cell to value entered in the input field in the side bar!
function enterValue(number){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 sheet.getRange("B11").setValue(number + 1) 
}
```

and the HTML for the Sidebar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="selectChange(this)">
    </select>
    <script>
      function selectChange(select) {
        google.script.run.changeSheet(select.value);
      }
      function playerNames(names) {
        var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = names[i];
          select.add(option);
        }
      }
      (function () { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(playerNames).getNames(); }());
    </script>
    <button onclick='f1()'>Select Athlete Name</button>
       </br>
    <!-- Create a input field to except a value form user, in this case there name -->
    Enter Value:
    <input type="number" id="number"><br>
    <!-- Create a button to send the value to the spreadsheet -->
    <button onclick='sendValue()'>Send Value</button>
<script>

  function f1() {
    google.script.run.getAddress();
  }

  function sendValue(){
   //Get the value of the input field 
   var number = document.getElementById("number").value
   //Log the value of input field in the web browser console (usually used for debugging)
   console.log(number)
   //Send the value of the text field as a arugment to the server side function.
   google.script.run.enterValue(number)
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create something from yours using my own sample data and not sure if this is what you want but I tried to adjust to anything I understood in your post. See output and code below.

#### Code.gs:

```
function ftball() {
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Sidebar');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Football");
  return [sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String),  // Retrieve names and
          sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String)]; // Stat types then send to Javascript (remove blank cells)
}

function enterValue(number, name, stat){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var namesLength = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String).length;
  var statsLength = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String).length;
  // where your name headers for the table starts (C6)
  var nameStartRow = 6;
  var nameStartCol = 3;
  // where your stat headers for the table (D5)
  var statStartRow = 5;
  var statStartCol = 4;
  // get list of names
  var names = sheet.getRange(nameStartRow, nameStartCol, namesLength, 1).getValues().flat();
  var stats = sheet.getRange(statStartRow, statStartCol, 1, statsLength).getValues().flat();
  // find the position by adjusting the index of name/stat to where the list starts
  var namePosition = names.indexOf(name) + nameStartRow;
  var statPosition = stats.indexOf(stat) + statStartCol;
  // get previous value, assign 0 if blank.
  var previousValue = sheet.getRange(namePosition, statPosition).getValue() || 0;
  sheet.getRange(namePosition, statPosition).setValue(parseInt(previousValue) + parseInt(number));  
}
```

#### HTML_Sidebar.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="mySelectNames"></select>
    <select id="mySelectStats"></select><br>
    Enter Value:
    <input type="number" id="number"><br>
    <button onclick='sendValue()'>Send Value</button>
    <script>
      function setOptions([names, stats]) {
        // set both names and stats drop down
        var select = document.getElementById("mySelectNames");
        for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = names[i];
          select.add(option);
        }
        // set default value to first option
        select.selectedIndex = 0;

        var select2 = document.getElementById("mySelectStats");
        for( var i=0; i<stats.length; i++ ) {
          var option2 = document.createElement("option");
          option2.text = stats[i];
          select2.add(option2);
        }
        select2.selectedIndex = 0;
      }
      function sendValue(){
        // send the values of name, stat and number then set as value
        var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("mySelectNames").value;
        var stat = document.getElementById("mySelectStats").value;

        //Send the value of the text field as a arugment to the server side function.
        google.script.run.enterValue(number, name, stat);
      }
      (function () { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setOptions).getData(); }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I modified both your html and apps script. But I hope it is near what you are wanting to achieve.
- The important bit here is how to find where to put the value given the name and stat. That's what I think is you can use and modify based on your data and wanted output.
- The code needs A and B to be not populated, thus the table is a bit to the right. But it can be avoided if we exactly know the list of names and stats.

Comment: Wow this is awesome. One piece I am looking to add would it be at all possible for the Value sent to be able to do the math rather than replace the value in the cell. For Example James ran 5 yards one play, next play he runs 6 more so James will show 11.

Comment: That would be doable. i have adjusted the script and updated the output. I just fetched the value of the cell first then add the new number there. @AndrewDunn, please check.

Comment: Works exactly like I dreamed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @AndrewDunn. Next time, it would be better if you could provide your expected output for questions like this. I was lucky enough to understand your point based on your basketball sheet. Glad to be able to provide you what you wanted. Good luck.